# Nested struct type in a template class

Tags: c++

```
template <typename vec1, typename vec2>
class fakevector
{
    public:
       /* Do something */
};



template <class A>
class caller
{
    public:

    struct typeList
    {
        struct typeOne
        {
            //...
        };
    };

    typedef fakevector<typeList::typeOne,int> __methodList;  /* This will trigger compile error */

};
```

The error messages I got are:

1. Error: type/value mismatch at
   argument 1 in template parameter
   list for ‘template class fakevector’
2. Error: expected a type, got ‘caller::typeList::typeOne’

   **If**  template  **is removed** from the caller class, **no error** will be reported,
   like this

   class caller
   {
       public:
          struct typeList
          { .... 
   };

I don't know the reason. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 typedef fakevector<typename typeList::typeOne,int> __methodList;
```

http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that typeList::typeOne is considered a dependant name here. After all, the fakevector typedef will never see a specialization of caller<>.

Comment: This is because you can specialize typeList and typeOne though. I.e.

template<> 
struct caller::typeList<int>::typeList { int typeOne; };

Here typeOne is not a type any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try `typedef fakevector<typename typeList::typeOne,int>`

The `typename` prefix to a name is required when the name

Appears in a template

Is qualified

Is not used as in a list of base class specifications or in a list of member initializers introducing a constructor definition

**Is dependent on a template parameter**

Furthermore, the `typename` prefix is not allowed unless at least the first three previous conditions hold.

Comment: Lol, did you completely change your answer just to avoid embarrassment?

Comment: @Maxim: Nopes, I had misinterpreted the question. :)

Comment: Okay, I guess it is not comp.lang.c++ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the compiler is in doubt what typeOne is.

```
typedef fakevector<typename typeList::typeOne,int>
```

should compile